# установка пакета pip на ПК, отключенном от интернета

Tags: python, pip

Есть пакет pip в формате pyproject.toml, который я пытаюсь установить на машине отключенной от интернета:

```
./foo
├── pyproject.toml
└── src
    └── foo
        └── __init__.py
```

pyproject.toml:

```
#
[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0", "wheel>=0.37.1"]

[project]
name = "foo"
version = "1.0"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
namespaces = false
where = [ "src" ]
```

__init__.py :

```
#!python

def foo():
    return 42
```

Нужные пакеты на машине стоят:

```
~/test_env/bin/python -m pip list 
...
setuptools          68.2.2
wheel               0.41.3
...
```

При попытке установки получаю ошибку:

```
[buildbot@cwb-test-rh8-01 tmp]$ ~/test_env/bin/python -m pip install ./foo                                                                                                                                                                    
Processing ./foo                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  Installing build dependencies ... error                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.                                                                                                                                                                    
  │ exit code: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f557c4bc940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/setuptools/                                                                                                                                                                  
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f557c4bcc40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/setuptools/                                                                                                                                                                  
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f557c4bcee0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/setuptools/                                                                                                                                                                  
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f557c4bcfa0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/setuptools/                                                                                                                                                                  
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f557c466250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/setuptools/                                                                                                                                                                  
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=61.0 (from versions: none)                                                                                                                                   
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=61.0                                                                                                                                                                              
      [end of output]                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.                                                                                                                                                        
error: subprocess-exited-with-error                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.                                                                                                                                                                      
│ exit code: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
╰─> See above for output.                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Если разрешаю обращаться к интернету, (через `export https_proxy=...`), то пакет успешно устанавливается, хотя setuptools и wheel при этом не обновляет.

Флаги pip --no-index --no-deps не меняют поведения.

Comment: В общем, попробуйте как вариант собрать пакет whl через `python -m build`, потом его установить. Не гарантирую что сработает (без интернета соберется и без интернета установится), проверить пока не могу.

Answer (score 2):

Флаг pip `--no-build-isolation` позволяет работать в изолированном режиме, хотя из названия флага кажется что наоборот.

Флаг может применяться как для установки, так и для сборки .whl файла:

`python -m pip install ./foo  --no-build-isolation`

`python -m pip wheel ./foo  --no-build-isolation`